# How do I script simple math functions in OSL?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, osl

I can't figure out how to script a simple inverse square root function node like the math node. The OSL language spec is mostly over my head since I don't have any programming experience.

Comment: Inverse square root - isn't that just a square?

Comment: @PGmath - probably just means 1/√X

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, looked at it again the next day and it was rather obvious.. just needed a break apparently

```
shader invrsquareroot(
    float x = 10.0,

    output float result = 0)
{
    result = inversesqrt(x);
}
```